# Partial view don't recognize some symbols from my C# code

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a asp.net mvc 3 application using Razor and several partial views. I took some time to realize that after every HTML markup I need to add `@` when continue with my code but here I have a partial view which returns a run time error complaining about missing closing `}` and the possible reason is that it's recognized as part of the HTML. I couldn't fix so I post it here:

```
@model List<DocumentFields>[]
@{
    int tempColumn = 1;    
}

<tr>
@foreach (var field in Model)
{
    if (field != null)
    {
        <td>
        @for (int i = 0; i < field.Count; i++)
        { 

                if (field[i].ColumnNo == tempColumn)
                {
                    @field[i].QuestionText
                    @field[i].FieldValue
                }
                else
                {
                    @(tempColumn++)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    @field[i].QuestionText
                    @field[i].FieldValue                    
                }
        }
        </td>
    }
}
```

I tried with changing the end of the view like this :

```
        </td>
    @}
@}
```

because these two are after an HTML element and probably could be recognized as part of the HTML as well but it doesn't fix the problem.

Seems that I am looking at the wrong direction. When I changed the code like this:

```
        if (field[i].ColumnNo == tempColumn)
        {
            @field[i].QuestionText
            @field[i].FieldValue
        }
        else
        {
            @field[i].QuestionText
            @field[i].FieldValue                    
        }
```

it's working, but this doesn't solve the problem, I need the incrementing index and the 's to properly format my output, am I using them incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@model List<DocumentFields>[]
@{
    int tempColumn = 1;    
}

<tr>
@foreach (var field in Model)
{
    if (field != null)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < field.Count; i++)
        { <td>

                if (field[i].ColumnNo == tempColumn)
                {
                    @field[i].QuestionText;
                    @field[i].FieldValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    @(tempColumn++);
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    @field[i].QuestionText;
                    @field[i].FieldValue;
                }
        </td>
        }

    }
} 
</tr>
```

Comment: Nope, here : `if (field != null)
    {
        <td>
        for (int i = 0; i < field.Count; i++)` if I don't put @ before the `for` everything is parsed as HTML.

Comment: it is not givine any error for me ... other than that of model ..as I dont have that...:(

Comment: Obviously I'm not very familiar with the way Razor is working but I guess it just don't parse the rest after the missing model error or the error is hidden. However I copy-paste it and in fact I don't get error just got everything after the `for` statement printed as HTML text.

Comment: Yeah, could be any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: the solution is to write it like this:                     `@:</td>
                    @:<td>`

Comment: @Leron - can you please tell what's the basic meaning of using `@:` ?

Comment: Well, as far as I understand and the one test I made with my code from the OP, I think this is the way to insert standard HTML tags/markup inside C# code. Don't get my words for granted since I just discover it today and didn't have much time to try different scenarios but... I guess this is it. So everything after `@:` is processed like HTML from the compiler.